# How can I remove all strings from tar file in Linux?

Tags: tar

I created a tar.gz file using `tar -cf file_1.tar` command. But, when I use `strings file_1.tar`, I see:

```
file
0000644
0001750
0001750
00000000000
014545
ustar  
arian
arian
```

How can I remove them?

Comment: An attempt to "remove" them makes no sense. They are integral parts of files packed into the tar file. If you "remove" them, you'll damage the file.

Comment: You can't just remove random parts of the file. The data is there for a reason. It's obvious and self-understanding, nothing more to explain here. It's like you tear out several pages from a book and expect the book to be still complete and intact.

Answer (score 1):

`strings` represents any plain text within the binary file, you should encrypt your tar file to hide its contents.

You can either use GPG with tar directly, like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817073/how-to-encrypt-after-creating-tar-archive).

Encrypt:

```
tar czvpf - file1.txt file2.pdf file3.jpg \
 | gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo aes256 -o myarchive.tar.gz
```

Decrypt:

```
gpg -d myarchive.tar.gz.gpg | tar xzvf -
```

Or you might want to consider storing your tar file using p7zip, which could be useful for compatibility with other operating systems using p7zip or 7-Zip. The reason you recompress the tar file is to preserve the unix permissions that ZIP files don't have compatibility for.

Install it first

```
sudo apt install p7zip-full
```

Encrypt:

```
7z a -p -mx=0 -mhe -t7z test.7z test.tar
```

When you run the encrypt command a prompt will ask you for the password you want to use.

Decrypt:

```
7z x test.7z
```

For more info on what these switches mean, see [this guide](https://www.pontikis.net/blog/easily-compress-encrypt-files-using-7z-p7zip-linux).